# Imprimir Valores Decimales de un Array 20x4 a través del Llamado de un Índice

Tags: java

Teniendo los siguientes Array de donde se tomaran los Valores a Trabajar:

```
        int [][] matrizasig = {{1,98,11}, {2,86,14}, {3,99,12}, {4, 89,12}, {5,89,12},{6,96,10}, {7,93,13}, {8,87,15}, {9,89,10},{10,92,10}, {11,99,15},{12,90,12}, {13,87,15}, {14,96,12}, {15,92,15}, {16,85,10}, {17,86,10}, {18,97,14}, {19,90,14}, {20,98,12}};
        int [][] matrizreg=  {{1,100,10}, {2,86,10}, {3,97,15}, {4,93,15},{5,94,13}, {6,93,13},{7,95,12},{8,85,11},{9,90,11},{10,90,12},{11,85,12}, {12,89,12},{13,85,12},{14,93,11},{15,89,10},{16,89,14},{17,93,12},{18,99,11},{19,93,13},{20,99,11}};
```

Se crea un Nuevo Array para Almacenar los resultados:

```
int[][] matrizResultado = new int[20][4];
```

Se Generan los Cálculos Necesarios Alimentando el Nuevo Array:

```
for(int i = 0; i<matrizResultado.length;i++){ // itera a través de las filas.
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizResultado[i].length; j++) // itera a través de las columnas.
                //Punto Distribucion
                matrizResultado[i][0] = matrizasig[i][0];
                //Diferencia de cajas
                matrizResultado[i][1] = matrizasig[i][1] - matrizreg[i][1];
                //Diferencia de tiempos
                matrizResultado[i][2] = matrizasig[i][2] - matrizreg[i][2];
                //Eficiencia
                matrizResultado[i][3] = ((matrizasig[i][2] - matrizreg[i][2]) * 100) / matrizasig[i][2];
        }
```

Se debe Generar la Salida de los Resultados de la Siguiente Manera:

```
Punto # 1
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 9.1%
Punto # 2
Diferencia de cajas = 0
Diferencia de tiempos = 4
Eficiencia = 28.6%
Punto # 3
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = -4
Eficiencia = -36.4%
Punto # 4
Diferencia de cajas = -4
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -25.0%
Punto # 5
Diferencia de cajas = -5
Diferencia de tiempos = 0
Eficiencia = 0.0%
Punto # 6
Diferencia de cajas = 3
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -30.0%
Punto # 7
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 7.7%
Punto # 8
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = 4
Eficiencia = 26.7%
Punto # 9
Diferencia de cajas = -1
Diferencia de tiempos = -1
Eficiencia = -10.0%
Punto # 10
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = -2
Eficiencia = -20.0%
Punto # 11
Diferencia de cajas = 14
Diferencia de tiempos = 3
Eficiencia = 20.0%
Punto # 12
Diferencia de cajas = 1
Diferencia de tiempos = 0
Eficiencia = 0.0%
Punto # 13
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = 3
Eficiencia = 20.0%
Punto # 14
Diferencia de cajas = 3
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 8.3%
Punto # 15
Diferencia de cajas = 3
Diferencia de tiempos = 5
Eficiencia = 33.3%
Punto # 16
Diferencia de cajas = -4
Diferencia de tiempos = -4
Eficiencia = -40.0%
Punto # 17
Diferencia de cajas = -7
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -30.0%
Punto # 18
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 3
Eficiencia = 21.4%
Punto # 19
Diferencia de cajas = -3
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 7.1%
Punto # 20
Diferencia de cajas = -1
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 8.3%
```

Genero el siguiente Código para obtener la Salida Solicitada:

```
for(int i = 0; i<matrizResultado.length;i++){ // itera a través de las filas.
            //for (int j = 0; j < matrizResultado[i].length; j++) // itera a través de las columnas.
                System.out.println("Punto # "+ matrizResultado[i][0]);
                System.out.println("Diferencia de cajas = "+ matrizResultado[i][1]);
                System.out.println("Diferencia de tiempos = "+ matrizResultado[i][2]);
                System.out.println("Eficiencia = "+ (double)matrizResultado[i][3] + "%");
        }
```

Pero la Salida Obtenida es la Siguiente:

```
Punto # 1
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 9.0%
Punto # 2
Diferencia de cajas = 0
Diferencia de tiempos = 4
Eficiencia = 28.0%
Punto # 3
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -25.0%
Punto # 4
Diferencia de cajas = -4
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -25.0%
Punto # 5
Diferencia de cajas = -5
Diferencia de tiempos = -1
Eficiencia = -8.0%
Punto # 6
Diferencia de cajas = 3
Diferencia de tiempos = -3
Eficiencia = -30.0%
Punto # 7
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 7.0%
Punto # 8
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = 4
Eficiencia = 26.0%
Punto # 9
Diferencia de cajas = -1
Diferencia de tiempos = -1
Eficiencia = -10.0%
Punto # 10
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = -2
Eficiencia = -20.0%
Punto # 11
Diferencia de cajas = 14
Diferencia de tiempos = 3
Eficiencia = 20.0%
Punto # 12
Diferencia de cajas = 1
Diferencia de tiempos = 0
Eficiencia = 0.0%
Punto # 13
Diferencia de cajas = 2
Diferencia de tiempos = 3
Eficiencia = 20.0%
Punto # 14
Diferencia de cajas = 3
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 8.0%
Punto # 15
Diferencia de cajas = 3
Diferencia de tiempos = 5
Eficiencia = 33.0%
Punto # 16
Diferencia de cajas = -4
Diferencia de tiempos = -4
Eficiencia = -40.0%
Punto # 17
Diferencia de cajas = -7
Diferencia de tiempos = -2
Eficiencia = -20.0%
Punto # 18
Diferencia de cajas = -2
Diferencia de tiempos = 3
Eficiencia = 21.0%
Punto # 19
Diferencia de cajas = -3
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 7.0%
Punto # 20
Diferencia de cajas = -1
Diferencia de tiempos = 1
Eficiencia = 8.0%
```

Como se Puede Observar la Salida que genera mi Código en el punto de "Eficiencia" no esta Teniendo en cuenta el Decimal que se Debe Imprimir, y por lo Tanto no se Logra el Objetivo Correcto.

¿Cómo Puedo Imprimir Correctamente la Salida de los Valores en "Eficiencia" para que tome ese Decimal que necesito Imprimir?

Dejo el Código Completo para ver si alguien detecta un error que yo no veo, o si conocen alguna manera de imprimir ese valor Doublé con un Decimal que me puedan indicar como lo hago.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] matrizasig = {{1,98,11}, {2,86,14}, {3,99,12}, {4, 89,12}, {5,89,12},{6,96,10}, {7,93,13}, {8,87,15}, {9,89,10},{10,92,10}, {11,99,15},{12,90,12}, {13,87,15}, {14,96,12}, {15,92,15}, {16,85,10}, {17,86,10}, {18,97,14}, {19,90,14}, {20,98,12}};
        int [][] matrizreg=  {{1,100,10}, {2,86,10}, {3,97,15}, {4,93,15},{5,94,13}, {6,93,13},{7,95,12},{8,85,11},{9,90,11},{10,90,12},{11,85,12}, {12,89,12},{13,85,12},{14,93,11},{15,89,10},{16,89,14},{17,93,12},{18,99,11},{19,93,13},{20,99,11}};
        int[][] matrizResultado = new int[20][4];
        
        for(int i = 0; i<matrizResultado.length;i++){ // itera a través de las filas.
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizResultado[i].length; j++) // itera a través de las columnas.
                //Punto Distribucion
                matrizResultado[i][0] = matrizasig[i][0];
                //Diferencia de cajas
                matrizResultado[i][1] = matrizasig[i][1] - matrizreg[i][1];
                //Diferencia de tiempos
                matrizResultado[i][2] = matrizasig[i][2] - matrizreg[i][2];
                //Eficiencia
                matrizResultado[i][3] = ((matrizasig[i][2] - matrizreg[i][2]) * 100) / matrizasig[i][2];
        }
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i<matrizResultado.length;i++){ // itera a través de las filas.
            //for (int j = 0; j < matrizResultado[i].length; j++) // itera a través de las columnas.
                System.out.println("Punto # "+ matrizResultado[i][0]);
                System.out.println("Diferencia de cajas = "+ matrizResultado[i][1]);
                System.out.println("Diferencia de tiempos = "+ matrizResultado[i][2]);
                System.out.println("Eficiencia = "+ (double)matrizResultado[i][3] + "%");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrizResultado` debe ser tipo double para que guarde los decimales y en el cálculo de eficiencia se debe hacer un casting en alguno de los operandos para que el resultado sea un double.

```
class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] matrizasig = {{1,98,11}, {2,86,14}, {3,99,12}, {4, 89,12}, {5,89,12},{6,96,10}, {7,93,13}, {8,87,15}, {9,89,10},{10,92,10}, {11,99,15},{12,90,12}, {13,87,15}, {14,96,12}, {15,92,15}, {16,85,10}, {17,86,10}, {18,97,14}, {19,90,14}, {20,98,12}};
        int [][] matrizreg=  {{1,100,10}, {2,86,10}, {3,97,15}, {4,93,15},{5,94,13}, {6,93,13},{7,95,12},{8,85,11},{9,90,11},{10,90,12},{11,85,12}, {12,89,12},{13,85,12},{14,93,11},{15,89,10},{16,89,14},{17,93,12},{18,99,11},{19,93,13},{20,99,11}};
        // cambio 1
        double[][] matrizResultado = new double[20][4];
        
        for(int i = 0; i<matrizResultado.length;i++){ // itera a través de las filas.
            for (int j = 0; j < matrizResultado[i].length; j++) // itera a través de las columnas.
                //Punto Distribucion
                matrizResultado[i][0] = matrizasig[i][0];
                //Diferencia de cajas
                matrizResultado[i][1] = matrizasig[i][1] - matrizreg[i][1];
                //Diferencia de tiempos
                matrizResultado[i][2] = matrizasig[i][2] - matrizreg[i][2];
                //Eficiencia
                // cambio 2
                matrizResultado[i][3] = ((matrizasig[i][2] - matrizreg[i][2]) * 100) / (double)matrizasig[i][2];
                
        }
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i<matrizResultado.length;i++){ // itera a través de las filas.
            //for (int j = 0; j < matrizResultado[i].length; j++) // itera a través de las columnas.
                System.out.println("Punto # "+ matrizResultado[i][0]);
                System.out.println("Diferencia de cajas = "+ matrizResultado[i][1]);
                System.out.println("Diferencia de tiempos = "+ matrizResultado[i][2]);
                System.out.println("Eficiencia = "+ Math.round(matrizResultado[i][3] * 10) / 10.0 + "%");
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eso me ayuda mucho, me da la salida con varios decimales, aunque solo debo imprimir el primer decimal redondeándolo... Tienes idea de como puedo imprimir solo el primer decimal??.

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta. En la impresión de la eficiencia ahí se redondea a un decimal.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo Lobos, no sabes la cantidad de intentos que realice para poder medio acercarme algo a lo que tu hiciste tan pronto, gracias por tu tiempo y por compartir tu conocimiento.